# How to add Username to AbpSession

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Currently, `AbpSession` only provides `UserId`, but I want to use `Username` instead because it is more explicit so how can I do that? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **UserManager** class to retrieve the current user's information.

Example usage in an application service:

```cs
 public async Task<string> GetCurrentUserName()
 {
      var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(AbpSession.GetUserId().ToString());
      return user.UserName;
 }
```

If you want to use it in a custom class, then inject **IAbpSession** and **UserManager** classes.

Comment: I will use it many times so that it will be better if I can put it in AbpSession instead of UserManager. Is there any solution, bro

Comment: create your own ApplicationServiceBase class inherited from current ApplicationServiceBase then add this code to this new base. Use it in all AppServices.